# Finding the square root of a number by using binary search

Tags: java, binary-search, square-root

I tried using binary search to find the square root of an integer, but some how I couldn't pass a few test cases.

I was able to pass mySqrt(4) = 2, but I wasn't able to pass mySqrt(2147395599)

Any ideas on where I messed up?

```
public static int mySqrt(int x) {
        int left = 0;
        int right = x;

        if(x < 2){
            return x;
        }
        while(left < right){
            int mid = left + ((right - left) / 2);

            if(mid * mid == x){
                return mid;

            }
            else if(mid * mid < x){
                left = mid + 1;
            }
            else{
                right = mid; 
            }
        }
        return left - 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because mid * mid will overflow. You should use long to avoid the overflow. Then cast it back to int when you return the result.

Try this code

```
public static int mySqrt(int x) {
    long left = 0;
    long right = x;

    if(x < 2){
        return x;
    }
    while(left < right){
        long mid = left + ((right - left) / 2);

        if(mid * mid == x){
            return (int)mid;

        }
        else if(mid * mid < x){
            left = mid + 1;
        }
        else{
            right = mid;
        }
    }
    return (int)(left - 1);
}
```

Comment: You're right! I forgot to considering the possibility of overflowing. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I didn't get that, we are passing integer value then how will mid overflow?

Comment: @piyush172 when mid is very large, for instance, when it is the max of integer, mid * mid will be larger than the max of integer, and overflow happens. you can try it

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version which handles doubles.

- It is recursive.
- It computes until a given precision is reached.

```
for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("sqrt("+i+") = " + sqrt(i));
}
```

Prints

```
sqrt(2) = 1.414213562373095
sqrt(3) = 1.7320508075688772
sqrt(4) = 2.0
sqrt(5) = 2.23606797749979
sqrt(6) = 2.449489742783178
sqrt(7) = 2.6457513110645907
sqrt(8) = 2.82842712474619
sqrt(9) = 3.0
```

```
public static double sqrt(double i) {
    return bsqrt(i, 0, i, 0);
}

static double prec = 10E-200;   

private static double abs(double d)  {
    return d < 0 ? -d : d;
}

private static double bsqrt(double i, double low, double high,
        double last) {
    double mid = (high + low) / 2;
    double d = last - mid;
    if (d < 0) {
        d = -d;
    }
    if (d < prec) {
        return mid;
    }
    double sqr = mid * mid;
    if (sqr < i) {
        return bsqrt(i, mid, high, mid);
    } else {
        return bsqrt(i, low, mid, mid);
    }
}
```

But a better way is to use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

```
static double prec = 10E-15;
public static double newtons(double i) {
    // initial guess
    double x = i / 2;

    double d = i;
    double nx = 0;
    while (abs(d) > prec) {
        nx = x - (x*x - i)/(2*x);
        d = nx - x;
        x = nx;
    }
    return nx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Square Root Calculation Using Binary Search Algorithm in Java

---

> **pseudo-code flow for Square Root Calculation Using Binary Search :**

1. Initialize variables ans, start, and end to track the search range.
2. Calculate the middle index mid as the average of start and end.
3. Enter a while loop as long as start is less than or equal to end.
4. Check if the square of the mid index is equal to the target number:

   - If true, assign mid to ans and return ans as the square root.
   - If the square of mid is greater than the target number:
5. Update end to mid - 1 to search in the lower half of the range.

   - If the square of mid is less than or equal to the target number:
6. Update ans to mid as a potential square root candidate.
7. Update start to mid + 1 to search in the upper half of the range.
8. Recalculate mid as the average of the updated start and end.
9. Repeat steps 4-7 until the search range is exhausted (start becomes greater than end).
10. Return ans as the closest square root found during the search.

> **The Iterative Approach**

```
public static int findSquareRoot(int num){
    int ans = -1;
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = num;
    long midIndex = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex ) / 2;

    while (startIndex <= endIndex){

        if((midIndex*midIndex) == num){
            ans = (int )midIndex;
            return ans;
        } else if ((midIndex*midIndex) > num) {
            endIndex = (int) midIndex - 1;
        }else {
            ans = (int) midIndex;
            startIndex = (int) midIndex + 1;
        }
        midIndex = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex ) / 2;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Discover Comprehensive Solution https://github.com/Amir36036/ds/blob/array/src/main/java/org/ds/array/FindSquareRootByBinarySearch.java

Answer (score -2):

This is like a binary search

The following code computes the [integer] square root of a number. If the number is not a
perfect square (there is no integer square root) , then it returns -1. It does this by successive
guessing. If n is 100, it first guesses SO. Too high? Try something lower - halfway between 1
and SO. What is its runtime?

```
int sqrt(int n) {
        return sqrt_helper(n, 1, n);
    }
     int sqrt_helper(int n, int min, int max) {
     if (max < min) return -1; // no square root
     int guess = (min + max) / 2·,
  if (guess *guess == n) { // found it!
      return guess;
  }else if (guess * guess < n) { II too low
      return sqrt_helper(n, guess + 1, max); // try higher
  } else { // too high
     return sqrt_helper(n, min, guess - l); //try lower
  }
}
```

credits: cracking the coding interview